# Can't access BCH from non-default wallets in blockchain.info

Tags: blockchain.info, passphrase

I have 3 additional wallets in my single blockchain.info account. When creating the passphrase and importing the 12 words in Electron Cash application, I was only able to see the amount from my default wallet.

Can anyone explain me how to access the BCH on the other wallets?
They have all funds pre-fork.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Kevin